# Calculating offset from two hex strings

Tags: c#, hex

I have a program that calculates offset but I do not have the source code for.  I am trying to see how this is calculated using C#.  The first input hex digit cannot be less than 80.  This is what I have written so far but it does not calculate the offset correctly:

```
private void getOffSet()
{

  // Default offset
  int defaultOffset = 0x0512;

  // Input
  byte byte1input = 0x80;
  byte byte2input = 0x00;
  int inValue = byte2input + (byte1input << 8);

  // Calculate offset
  int outValue = inValue + defaultOffset;

  // Convert integer as a hex in a string variable
  string hexValue = outValue.ToString("X"); 

}
```

Any help correcting this function to calculate the correct offset would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you before hand.

Comment: *Why* should those values produce those offsets? You've given sample values but no rules that they follow.

Comment: You need to explain what is a correct offset. For your situation what do the two bytes represent and how are they used to create your offset value.

Comment: Is there a math formula you forgot to mention in the post?

Comment: Ja, I do not have the source code for the original project.  All I know is that those two numbers are the only thing required to produce the offset.  Jon, I do not have the rules since I do not have the source code for the original project.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to test 22 82 or 82 22?  The number you're forming in the line that reads "int inValue = byte1input + (byte2input << 8);" is 22 82, but the comment says 82 22.

Comment: Tony, you are right, it should be int inValue = byte2input + (byte1input << 8);  (I was testing 82 22, it is the 4th one from the bottom up in the examples)

Comment: @user3297350 What language was the original program written in? Could you disassemble it? Also, you must have *some* idea of what the offset represents - what does it get used for? What is the purpose of the original program?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: @user3297350 Please stop deleting huge swathes of your post. In its current form, there is absolutely no link between the question and the answer, and Bart seems to have pulled a formula from the air as if by magic. The question's lack of applicability to any future readers already makes it a candidate for closing as far as I'm concerned; making it incomprehensible on top of that clinches it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it describes a one-off problem with no applicability for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function matches your list. It is, however, a wild guess of course as there is no way I can match it with the original program and I have no idea what these offsets mean.

```
private void getOffSet(byte one, byte two)
{
  byte baseByte = 0x80;

  int defaultOffset = 0x0418;

  int mul = (one - baseByte) % 8;

  int result = mul * 0x2000 + defaultOffset;
  result += two * 0x0020;

  Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("X"));
}
```